# Stacking words above of a summation symbols

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

For this equation:

```
P_{\lambda \sigma} = 2 \sum\limits_{i}^{\hbox{occupied  molecular  orbitals} } c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
```

I want the words "occupied molecular orbitals" stacked 3 high.  I tried `\vbox`, but that did not work.

Comment: what do you mean with "stacked 3 high"?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placing the string "occupied molecular orbitals" above the `\sum` symbol, I'd place it *below* the symbol and group it with the `i` summation index.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\smashoperator" macro
\begin{document}
\[
  P_{\lambda\sigma}
  = 2 \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{
                              i\in\text{\,occupied}\\
                              \text{molecular}\mathstrut\\
                              \text{orbitals}\mathstrut}}}
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

### `\substack`

A solution with `amsmath`' macro `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  P_{\lambda \sigma} =
  2 \sum\limits_{i}^{
    \substack{\text{occupied}\\\text{molecular\vphantom{p}}\\\text{orbitals}}
  }
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \substack]

The purpose of `\vphantom` is the better line spacing.

### `tabular`

```
Also a `tabular` works:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  P_{\lambda \sigma} =
  2 \sum\limits_{i}^{
    \text{\scriptsize
      \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}occupied\\molecular\\orbitals\end{tabular}%
    }
  }
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabular]

### `\mathclap`

Macro `\mathclap` lies to TeX, that its contents does not have width. Therefore, it can be used to place the superscript without affecting the horizontal spacing below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  P_{\lambda \sigma} =
  2 \sum\limits_{i}^{
    \mathclap{%
      \substack{\text{occupied}\\\text{molecular\vphantom{p}}\\\text{orbitals}}
    }%
  }
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \mathclap]

### plain TeX

```
$$
  P_{\lambda \sigma} =
  2 \sum\limits_{i}^{
    \hbox to 0pt{%
      \hss
      \vbox{%
        \sevenrm
        \baselineskip=8pt
        \halign{\hss#\hss\cr occupied\cr molecular\cr orbitals\cr}%
      }\hss
    }
  }
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
$$

\bye
```

> [image: Result plain TeX]

Comment: There's also `\smashoperator` from `mathtools`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `\Longstack` in `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
P_{\lambda \sigma} = 2 \sum\limits_{i}^{\scriptsize\Longstack{occupied  molecular  orbitals} 
  } c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you didn't want the spacing of the text to affect the surrounding math, add a `\mathclap`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
P_{\lambda \sigma} = 2 \sum\limits_{i}^{\mathclap{\scriptsize\Longstack{occupied  molecular  orbitals} 
  }} c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the `\substack` from `amsmath` is another way of approaching this.

because there are no descenders on the second and third lines, a `\mathstrut`
is added to keep the lines a constant distance apart.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\[
 P_{\lambda \sigma}
  = 2 \sum_{i}^{\substack{\text{occupied}\\
              \mathstrut\text{molecular}\\
              \mathstrut\text{orbitals}}}
  c_{\lambda i} c_{\sigma i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]